# Rails image generation & attachment w/ paperclip

Tags: ruby-on-rails, image-processing

In my current project, I need to create an image from two others (one serve as background, the other one is "put" over), and attach it to an object. I'm used to do the attachment part with paperclip, but I've never dealt with image generation yet. I know that paperclip can do some things like that (resize pictures, etc), but I don't know how to do what I want. Is there enough in paperclip itself to do this ? What are tools given to me then ? If not, what are the prefered options ?

Thanks for your time!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We ended up using `Paperclip.run` to generate the image using imagemagick.

Answer (score 0):

Paperclip is a cool plugin which has almost all necessary functions like resizing, cropping, and storing images in different sizes. I have been using it for a long and never faced any issue. It gives you an option of remote file uploads too (like amazon s3). Attachment-foo is also a similar plugin having same set of features. But if you think, paperclip does not fulfill your requirements, you can give a try to [Carrierwave](https://github.com/jnicklas/carrierwave) which is interestingly growing than paperclip and nice features too.